# Перенаправление с RewriteRule в .htaccess

Tags: .htaccess

Здравствуйте, не могу разобраться в файле `.htaccess`. Хочу, чтобы при заходе на `http://site.ru/product/414` открывалась страничка `http://site.ru/product.php?id=414`, что для этого нужно вписать в .htaccess? Гуглил, читал, не справился.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В вашем случае могу посоветовать

```
RewriteRule ^product/([0-9]{1,5})/?$ /product.php?id=$1
```

Тогда будет работать как ссылка `http://site.ru/product/414`, так и ссылка `http://site.ru/product/414/`.

Comment: Само собой RewriteEngine On в начале файла .htaccess обязательно;
пояснения ([0-9]{1,5}) это значит, что будет обрабатывать, если после product/ стоят цифры от 1 - 5 длиной.

Comment: я так и делал,и не работало, а сейчас разобрался такое вот дело:  
если стоит код RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /sitemap.php [L,QSA] то http://site.ru/product/414/ не пашет, если убрать реврайт sitemap.php то все работает, как сделать что бы и то и от работало?

Comment: сделайте из этой строки вот такую
RewriteRule ^sitemap/?$ /sitemap.php
и будете попадать на карту сайта по ссылке http://site.ru/sitemap/
а то у вас получается что любой запрос на сайт который не попадает никуда он кидает сразу на сайт мап. для таких целей делают вот так еще
ErrorDocument 404 /sitemap.php  ---это ставят в начало файла!

Comment: А вот если такой запрос? `http://site.ru/user.php?id=219&page=1&sort=name&view=10` нельзя превратить в `http://site.ru/user=219/page=1/sort=name/view=10`, я просто давно хочу понять логику RewriteRule, никак не пойму, наверно, читаю не те мануалы. (

Comment: конкретно для этого --
RewriteRule ^user=(.*)/page=(.*)/sort=(.*)/view=(.*)/?$ /user.php?id=$1&page=$2&sort=$3&view=$4
в скобках после точек везде звездочка!!! *
она просто тут не ставится как есть.

Comment: @Grimon, в комментариях работает тег `<pre></pre>` и тильда для оформления кода)

Answer (score 3):

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^(\d+)$ /product.php?id=$1 [L]
```

Именно конкретно для вашего случая -

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^(414)$ /product.php?id=414 [L]
```

Гуглите по запросу mod rewrite clean url